# Import org.springframework in a maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, netbeans

I am learning Spring in maven environment. I am using netbeans.

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.davidsalter.cookbook</groupId>
<artifactId>springMavenTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

And *spring.context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar* appears under **Dependencies**. Under **Java Dependencies** i only have JDK1.8.

When i have to configure my beans in a java class using @Configuration and @Bean annotations i can't import *org.springframework*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you just create a maven project in NetBeans. The maven dependencies you declared in `pom.xml` will be downloaded and listed in the `Dependencies` folder.

Right click on `Dependencies` folder and click on `Download Declared Dependencies` to reload the dependency. If still failed, you may need to check your maven proxy in `setting.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Update you project.
By doing Alt + F5 and then select your project then click Ok

Else right click on your project -> Maven -> Update Project.
Make sure you are connected to the internet to download all these spring dependencies.

Comment: I am using netbeans, if i right click my maven project from the project window i don't have any "Maven" option. If i select "Build with Dependencies" i have  an error with with this [link](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException) . I added the complete pom in the post

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems. I added the following to the pom:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
```

It seems to work ....